# How to properly send data via MINA?

Tags: java, sockets, nio, apache-mina

I'm attempting to get started with MINA, and all of the examples seem to have data written to the session, rather than making use of a method that can write the same type of data over and over.

I'm trying to make use of `org.apache.mina.filter.codec.demux.MessageEncoder` / `MessageDecoder` to `encode` / `decode` messages, which will allow me to always perform the task in a central location instead of doing it inline in the code, like the examples do.

Let's say I have a `ProtocolCodecFactory` (which extends `DemuxingProtocolCodecFactory`) that has a `LoginRequestEncoder` (which implements `MessageEncoder<LoginRequest>`, and was added via the factory's `addMessageEncoder` method).  Does that mean that instead of directly calling `session.write()` with the username/password data, I should instead do something like this?

```
LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest(username, password);
new ProtocolCodecFactory()
    .getEncoder(session)
    .encode(session, request, someProtocolEncoderOutput);
```

I'm not going to lie...MINA seems like it's supposed to simplify the networking process, and I'm sure it will when I get a handle on it, but I'm thoroughly confused right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out you can simple send a request via [IoSession.write()](http://mina.apache.org/report/trunk/apidocs/org/apache/mina/core/session/IoSession.html#write%28java.lang.Object%29).  Here is a simple example based upon my original question:

```
LoginRequest request = new LoginRequest(username, password);
session.write(request);
```